# What is the right Syntax query for attaching image in another table?

Tags: c#, sql

I have two tables called `TBL_Students` from a database called `DB_Students` and `TBL_Attendance` from `DB_SeatPlan`. I want to get the signatures of the students listed in `TBL_Attendance` from the `TBL_Students`. Is this the right query?

```
INSERT INTO TBL_Attendance (columnName) VALUES (v1, v2...etc)
    SELECT columnName 
    FROM TBL_Students 
    WHERE column = 'value'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INSERT INTO . .  SELECT` with `DB` Name :

```
INSERT INTO DB_SeatPlan.<schema>.TBL_Attendance (columnName)
   SELECT . . . 
   FROM DB_Students.<schema>.TBL_Students
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want:

```
INSERT INTO TBL_Attendance (. . ., signature)
    SELECT v1, . . ., s.signature
    FROM TBL_Students s
    WHERE column = 'value';
```

That is, you would put the constants into the `SELECT`, add the `signature` column to the list of columns being inserted, and select the value from `tbl_students`.  (This assumes that the columns you are interested in are called `signature`.)

Note that normally this would be accomplished with a `JOIN`.  One reason for copying the value over would be if it changes over time, and you want the value at that point in time.  Otherwise, don't duplicate the data.  Just store it once and use `JOIN` to fetch it when you want it.